# Type mismatch: cannot query column with data type varchar when the column is type varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query:

```
select staff_id from table1;
```

Result:

```
staff_id
-----
3032
3036
3037
3037
```

Query:

```
select staff_id from table1 where staff_id = '3032'
```

Result:

```
staff_id
-----
```

with no results

Why can't I query for '3032'?

Below is some additional information you may need.

Query:

```
select staff_id from table1 where staff_id = 3032
```

Result:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3032 ' to data type int.

Query:

```
select staff_id from table1 where staff_id = '3032 '
```

Result:

```
staff_id
-----
```

with no results

Query:

```
select * from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'staff_id';
```

Part of the result:

```
TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME IS_NULLABLE DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
table1      staff_id    NO          varchar   5                        5
```

Answer from @David דודו Markovitz:

Query:

```
select cast(staff_id  as varchar(5)) from table1 where staff_id like '3032%'
```

Comment: Note the error message. You have white character at the end of the number. `'3032 '`

Comment: @DaleK if I don't, then how would I show that there really isn't any output for my query?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz , in my CSV file, the data is stored as a integer. In my create, i specified varchar(5). How would I get rid of the space after 3032?

Comment: In a CSV file there are no data types. You either got a space there or you don't.

Comment: @wel That's a different question, so please open a new question. Please then include a sample csv file that demonstrates the problem behaviour, and the exact code used to load that file.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz unfortunately, when i try select * from table1 where staff_id = '3032 ' with the space at the end, the same thing comes out, which is no result. i've editted my main question to show this result.

Comment: The whitespace character may be a carriage return, or a tab, or some other whitespace, not necessarily a literal space.

Comment: You said it's a space. I used the term "white character". Please run and share the results: `select cast(staff_id  as varbinary(100)) from table1 where staff_id like '3032%'`

Comment: David asked for the result of casting to VARBINARY, not VARCHAR...

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz thanks! that worked. I would accept that as your answer, if you are planning on actually answering

Comment: Please don't add the answer to your question, if the commenter doesn't answer, then feel free to self answer with an actual answer.

Comment: A fuzzy search is not the "correct answer". `varbinary` is a way to diagnose the issue, and from your side should understand what the source of the white character is and fix it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know people have already mentioned this, but you have a white character at the end of the number. Also, I know it worked for you, but please don't cast as type varchar if you want to diagnose and issue. Use varbinary (as so pointed out).

```
select cast(staff_id  as varbinary(100)) from table1 where staff_id like '3032%'
```

In order to select those values with white characters at the end, do it like so:

```
select staff_id from table1 where staff_id like '3032%'
```

Answer (score -2):

There may be some additional characters in the value stored in the field. So in these cases use % in both sides to get the rows you are looking for.

```
select staff_id from table1 where staff_id like '%3032%'
```

Once you have the results from the above query, you can filter again to the exact row you are looking for.

Comment: The error message already explicitly shows the whitespace character ***after*** the numerals.

Comment: while this is the correct answer, i'm waiting to see if @David דודו Markovitz is going to write his comment as an answer, since he did answer first